# What is a HAN in networking?

Tags: networking

What is a HAN in networking, how does it work and when should I use one?

Answer (score 3):

The xAN designations (LAN, WAN, CAN, MAN, etc.) are loosely defined, with no formal definitions through standards bodies, and they may mean different things to different people.

Having said that, HAN (Home Area Network) is a relatively new term relating to the deployment of a network in a home environment, and it represents a network about which you should inquire on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), rather than on a site for business networks.

Comment: Ok thanks, I vote to move the question to Super User in this case.